# Unable to implement this python program to find the sum of the subarray with maximum sum of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, max

Want To: Return the sum of maximum sum subarray of 2D array

In the following program, I am first calculating the sum of the maximum sum subarray whose boundary columns are L and R where L runs from 0 to (cols-1) and R runs from L to (cols-1), cols are number of columns and rows are number of rows. Then clearly, required answer is maximum of all these values. I am also updating the maximum sum, max, along.

[See here for the famous algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-rectangle-in-a-2d-matrix-dp-27/)

My function max_sum_of_subarray_in_1D_array(A, n) returns the sum of maximum subarray of 1D array in O(N) time and this function is working perfectly.

```
def max_sum_of_subarray_in_1D_array(A, n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        A[i] = max(A[i], A[i]+A[i-1])
    iMax = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if A[i] > A[iMax]:
            iMax = i

    return A[iMax]


def max_sum_of_subarray_in_2D_array(A, rows, cols):
    temp = []
    max = -1000000

    for L in range(0, cols):
        for i in range(0, rows):
            temp.append(0)
        for R in range(L, cols):
            for i in range(0, rows):
                temp[i] += A[i][R]
            val = max_sum_of_subarray_in_1D_array(temp, rows);
            if val > max:
                max = val

    return max


A = [[1, 2, -1, -4, -20],
    [-8, -3, 4, 2, 1],
    [3, 8, 10, 1, 3],
    [-4, -1, 1, 7, -6]]

print(max_sum_of_subarray_in_2D_array(A, 4, 5))
```

However I am getting wrong output of 1024

Correct Output: 29

Can someone please point out where I am doing wrong. I have looked over again and again, can't find mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you had two issues in your code:-

1. You method `max_sum_of_subarray_in_1D_array()` is not working properly.
2. Inside of `for L in range(0, cols):` loop you need to reassign `temp = []`, otherwise you will keep appending values and the sum will increase, which gives you wrong output.

I am posting updated code, please refer to it.

```
def max_sum_of_subarray_in_1D_array(a, size): 
  max_so_far = -1000000
  max_ending_here = 0

  for i in range(0, size): 
    max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i] 
    if (max_so_far < max_ending_here): 
      max_so_far = max_ending_here 

    if max_ending_here < 0: 
      max_ending_here = 0   
  return max_so_far 


def max_sum_of_subarray_in_2D_array(A, rows, cols):
  temp = []
  maxValue = -1000000

  for L in range(0, cols):
    temp = []
    for i in range(0, rows):
      temp.append(0)
    for R in range(L, cols):
      for i in range(0, rows):
        temp[i] += A[i][R]
      val = max_sum_of_subarray_in_1D_array(temp, rows)
      if val > maxValue:
        maxValue = val

  return maxValue


A = [[1, 2, -1, -4, -20],
  [-8, -3, 4, 2, 1],
  [3, 8, 10, 1, 3],
  [-4, -1, 1, 7, -6]]

print(max_sum_of_subarray_in_2D_array(A, 4, 5))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much. But I am still unable to figure out why my algorithm for 1D array is not working :(

Comment: @AshwiniPatil generally in order to understand bug in my program, I take paper and pen and go step by step to see what might be the problem.